# How can I show this function is discontinuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

so I think this function is discontinuous, but I'm not so sure how to calculate the limit for the first function to prove that both are different, any ideas how should I do it?
\begin{array}{l l}
    \dfrac{x^6+9x^4y^2-9x^2y^4-y^6}{(x^2+y^2)^3} & \quad \text{for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$}\\
    -1 & \quad \text{for $(x,y)=(0,0)$}
  \end{array}
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For $x \neq 0$,
$$f(x,x)=\frac{0}{8x^6}=0$$
Therefore, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x,x)=0$.

But $f(0,0)=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to calculate limit at $(0,0)$ along a path say $y=0$. this turns out to be $+1$. but the value at the value of the function is $-1$ at $(0,0)$.